# float action button list view

Tags: android, button

good morning,

i work the first time with a float action button (fab).
with this code part, my fab will be visible in the right bottom corner of my custom list view.

```
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/fab_add_product"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_24dp" />
```

the logical problem is, that the text of the row, which is befind the fab, will be not visible.

how can i solve this situation / problem?

Comment: fab overlays itself on the base layout. So it will always be on it, hiding the content below it. What do you expect as a solution?

Comment: Hide the FAB when the list hits the end of the line. In that way the last row is visible/readable.

Answer (score 0):

In that case go for semi tranparent background

```
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/fab_add_product"
            android:background="#55000000" 
// added newly ive added 55 with 000000 for black you,can change opacity and color using [00- FF] [000000 - FFFFFF]
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_24dp" />
```

Comment: sry but this doesn't work. the background color will not change to black and the opacity isn't active too